# I am trying to send an email in a C# mvc app and I get Error message: Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

I have a app that uses boiler plate code from aws ses docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-an-email-using-sdk-programmatically.html. This is my `EmailSender.cs` file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Runtime;
using Amazon.SimpleEmail;
using Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;


namespace amaranth.Helpers
{
    public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
    {
        private ApiEndpoints _endpoints;

        public EmailSender(IOptions<ApiEndpoints> _options)
        {
            _endpoints = _options.Value;
        }

        public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
        {
            using (var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
            {
                var sendRequest = new SendEmailRequest
                {
                    Source = "<A DOMAIN THAT I DO OWN>",
                    Destination = new Destination
                    {
                        ToAddresses =
                        new List<string> { email }
                    },
                    Message = new Message
                    {
                        Subject = new Content(subject),
                        Body = new Body
                        {
                            Html = new Content
                            {
                                Charset = "UTF-8",
                                Data = htmlMessage
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    // If you are not using a configuration set, comment
                    // or remove the following line 
                    //ConfigurationSetName = configSet
                };
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sending email using Amazon SES...");
                    var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(sendRequest);
                    Console.WriteLine("The email was sent successfully.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The email was not sent.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + ex.Message);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My variables `email`, `subject` and `htmlMessage` are all properly formatted. Also I verified the domain (represented with `<A DOMAIN THAT I DO OWN>` in the code).  See here:
[image]

I am also out of the sandbox and I even created an `IAM` user to handle email:
[image]

But when I run my app, the email isn't sent and I get this error: `Error message: Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.`

I am not sure what the problem is but I noticed that I'm not really declaring my credentials anywhere. But... I don't even know where I would put the credentials. The amazon ses docs don't really appear to specify where the credentials go. Can somebody show me where I'm going wrong and where my credentials go?

UPDATE:
I added a BasicAWSCredentials where _endpoints.EmailUsername is my "Access key ID" and _endpoints.EmailPassword" is my Secret Access Key for the user I created specifically for this app.

```
var awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(_endpoints.EmailUsername, _endpoints.EmailPassword);
using (var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(awsCreds, RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
```

But I got this error:
`Error message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working. It was a strange fix. First I added my credentials to the code:

```
AWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(_endpoints.EmailUsername, _endpoints.EmailPassword);
using (var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(awsCreds, RegionEndpoint.USEast2))
```

But then I got this error: `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided`. This was the difficult error to get around. I tried a lot of stuff but then I came across this post https://adithya.dev/aws-signaturedoesnotmatch-error/. I generated another credential for my aws user that had a `+` closer to the end of the name and then it worked perfectly. I think this is a weird bug in the C# (and possibly other languages) AWS code.